# Fuzzy matching unordered strings

Tags: java, string, fuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I have a bunch of strings, that are completely random in wording, and I need to find the best match to keywords. I've tried using triplets, and Levenshtein's algorithm and I'm still getting irregular results. I've tried sorting the string by its first character, then running Levenshtein's algorithm so that I would be able to get a more accurate result, but that didn't help.

My keywords are maybe 1-3 words each, but the target string I'm trying to match with is sometimes >10-20 words. Is there any other algorithm that I could use that will effectively match keywords to a correct string?

Triplets approach I tried using this:

```
ratio = (3*|A ∩ B|)/(|A| + |B|)
```

where A and B are arrays of triplets (3 characters of a word, generated by indexing by 1) such as

```
stackoverflow -> sta, tac, ack, cko, kov, ove, ver, erf, rfl, flo, low
```

and A  ∩ B is the similar triplets in A and B. This method seemed effective, but it ended up giving me a lot of irregular results.

So is there any way to improve on this fuzzy matching?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. The Levenstein algorithm should give you the count of characters you'd need to edit. Afterwards you'd need to order the results to get the closest match... it's not very effictive (`O(n*m)*z + O(z*log z)` where z is the length of the array of tripplets, n the length of the first string and m the length of the second.) but there is no better way...

Comment: My problem is that some strings are written in a way that gives them a better value from Levenstein's algorithm when it's not the match I would want. I guess I'll tinker with the algorithm or something.